# Reputation gain displayed incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, recent-activity

1. I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741010/c-program-to-compare-integers-without-using-logical-operators/1741104#1741104) and received three upvotes at the time of writing:

   [link text http://student.science.uva.nl/~sschroev/so/29903/cq.png](http://student.science.uva.nl/~sschroev/so/29903/cq.png)
2. I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741205/a-select-question/1741230#1741230) but then deleted it.
3. I look at my "recent activity" tab and see no mention of the deleted post (of course), but **four** upvotes for the answer which supposedly received three upvotes:
   [alt text http://student.science.uva.nl/~sschroev/so/29903/ra.png](http://student.science.uva.nl/~sschroev/so/29903/ra.png)
4. I then very briefly undeleted the deleted question. The "recent activily" display was not updated.

**Question:** what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see four upvotes in the database -- the /recent page is correct. The denormalized post score count is off.

This can happen (depends on client javascript timing issues) and is dealt with automatically. As part of the daily cron / scheduled tasks, each post is verified that it's in sync with the votes table.

So basically just wait 24-36 hours. The /recent page is correct.

Comment: Good! Better that way than the other way around ;)